# Conway's Game of Life Not Changing Anything

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

So, I have to do the Conway's Game of Life with these 5 rules below:

1. A cell that has fewer than two live neighbors dies
2. A cell that has more than 3 live neighbors dies
3. A cell that is dead and has exactly 3 live neighbors comes to life
4. All edge cells stay 0
5. All other cells maintain their state

   Example:

   ```
   >>> A = [ [0,0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0]]

    >>> printBoard(A)
   00000
   00100
   00100
   00100
   00000

   >>> A2 = next_life_generation( A )
   >>> printBoard(A2)
   00000
   00000
   01110
   00000
   00000

   >>> A3 = next_life_generation( A2 )
   >>> printBoard(A3)
   00000
   00100
   00100
   00100
   00000
   ```

   and so on... .

Notice, that `next_life_generation( A )` returns a new board, so I can keep re-binding A to each successive generation. This is my code so far:

```
import sys
def printBoard( A ):
    """ this function prints the 2d list-of-lists
        A without spaces (using sys.stdout.write)
    """
    for row in A:
        for col in row:
            sys.stdout.write( str(col) )
        sys.stdout.write( '\n' )

def countNeighbors(row, col, A):
    count = 0
    for row in range(1, len(A) - 1):
        for col in range(1, len(A) - 1):
            if A[row][col] == 1:
                count += 1
    return count

def next_life_generation(A):
    for row in range(1, len(A) - 1):
        for col in range(1, len(A) - 1):
            if A[row][col] == 0 and countNeighbors(row, col, A) == 3:
                A[row][col] = 1
            if countNeighbors(row, col, A) < 2:
                A[row][col] = 0
            elif countNeighbors(row, col, A) > 3:
                A[row][col] = 0
    return A
```

The problem that I am having is that it my code doesnt change anything it just prints out the same thing:

```
>>> A = [ [0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,1,0,0],
      [0,0,1,0,0],
      [0,0,1,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0]]
>>> printBoard(A)
00000
00100
00100
00100
00000
>>> A2=next_life_generation(A)
>>> printBoard(A2)
00000
00100
00100
00100
00000
```

I would really appreciate someone help!

Comment: http://pythontutor.com

Comment: What is printBoard(A) ? I don't see such  a function in your code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: One common mistake people make when implementing life: if you update each cell in the matrix in-place, then eventually you can no longer accurately determine each neighbor's state at time T-1, because some of them have been updated to contain their state at time T. You need two matrices: one holding the old state, one that will hold the new state.

Answer (score 0):

In your definition for countNeighbors, what are you looping through?
You're going from row = 1,...,|A|-1
First, in python, range starts from min inclusive and excludes max. So range you want to use is

`range(0,len(A))`

But that't still not right. You're looping through all rows and columns (once you correct the range errors here as well) in next_life_generation. So I believe you want to check immediate neighbours around the cell for each value of row and column. I think you realise this, that's why you pass row and col values to check 
`countNeighbors(row, col, X) == 3:`
But again, what are you looping through?
From 0 to |A| for both rows and column. So each time you're summing the total for the whole matrix, which in your example is always 3.

Here's something to try:

```
def countNeighbors(row, col, A):
count = 0
for r in range(max(row-1,0), min(row+2, len(A))):
    for c in range(max(row-1,0), min(row+2, len(A))):
        if A[r][c] == 1:
            count += 1
return count
```

Notice the min and max (and notice min(row+2, len(A)) because range will stop at min(row+1, or len(A)-1), so that you don't get index out of bounds error.